# Declared variable in style file

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to read about `.bst` files from [Tame the Beast](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). On page 39, there is this example for a multiplication function:

```
INTEGERS { a b }

FUNCTION {mult}
{
  ’a := %% we store the first value
  ’b := %% we store the second value

  b #0 < %% We remember the sign of b, and
    {#-1 #0 b - ’b :=} %% then consider its absolute value.
    {#1} %%
  if$
  ...
```

why are there `b`'s that are not preceded by a `'`? Shouldn't all `b`'s refer to the same `b`, the `b` that was declared inside `INTEGERS`, and should be preceded by a `'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of BibTeX is such that

```
#1 'a :=
```

is an assignment, with the variable named `a` being set to the value `1`, while

```
a #1 =
```

is a comparison, with the value of the variable `a` inserted and compared to `1`.

BibTeX is a stack language, so more generally `'a` leaves the *name* of the variable on the stack while just `a` leaves the value on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The line `{#-1 #0 b - ’b :=}` means: set the value of the variable whose name is `'b` to  the value of obtained by the operation where the value of one of the operand is `b` (the value currently stored by the variable `'b`.

Comment: So `b` refers to the value of the variable whose name is `'b`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct